# Can a grammar checking library be used to find meaningful sentences in random strings?

Tags: python, grammar

If I have a random string that has a sentence in it somewhere.
"e,ktdo.ba Hello, my name is CodeMaker efq ,z unqusiug.."

Can I use a grammar checker to find the sentence without knowing what it is ? I know finding individual words is as easy as using a list that has all the words used in the language and check if any of the words are in the string (or sometimes, even most words will do) but I don't think it's even worthy to discuss making a list of ***all*** sentences. I want to know if grammar checkers can "understand" sentence structures and find sentences in random strings (I would prefer a python library but if there isn't any that does what I wan't, I will have to use another language). Or maybe there is a library that isn't a grammar checker but can do what I want (which is doubtful because what I want to do is pretty specific). Is this even possible without AI ?

Comment: First of all, this has already been done by many platforms. For desktop software we have MS Word, for web-based we have Grammarly. This does not require AI since grammar is a set of rules, which is not difficult to be implemented ( just a tedious task ).

Comment: MS Word can find sentences within random strings ? Keep in mind that I don't know what the sentences are but I want the computer to find them.

Comment: If what I wanted to do was as simple as you say, then I think I would've come accross it as I was making the massive amount of google searches.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do it without AI. Just step through each position in the string, and ask the checker if a grammatical sentence begins at that point. That's assuming the checker can return success when there's still some (unparseable) input remaining -- if not, you'd have to iterate over start *and* end positions, asking if the specified substring constitutes a grammatical sentence.

That's if the checker is a black box. If you know more about the grammar/language, you could improve efficiency. E.g., if, as you suggest, you have a list of all valid words in the language, then you could first find all spans of valid words separated by whitespace, then only submit those to checking.